# How to rebuild tabs in CupertinoTabScaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `CupertinoTabScaffold` with 4 tabs, and I have a variable that is responsible for authorization, I need to update the tabs when this variable changes

My `CupertinoTabScaffold` :

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
          controller: _controller,
          key: myKey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            inactiveColor: const Color.fromRGBO(43, 46, 74, 1),
            activeColor: const Color.fromRGBO(232, 69, 69, 1),
            iconSize: 27,
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: onItemTapped,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house), activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.square_list), activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.square_list_fill)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart), activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart_fill)),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person), activeIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_fill)),
            ],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                return CupertinoTabView(
                  navigatorKey: tabNavKeys[index],
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomePage(),
                );
              case 1:
                return CupertinoTabView(
                  navigatorKey: tabNavKeys[1],
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                      child: CatalogPage(),
                    );
                  },
                );
              case 2:
                return currentIndex == 2 ? CupertinoTabView(
                  navigatorKey: tabNavKeys[2],
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                      child: ShoppingBag(),
                    );
                  },
                ) : Container();
              case 3:
                return CupertinoTabView(
                  navigatorKey: tabNavKeys[3],
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                      child: UserProfileScaffold(),
                    );
                  },
                );
              default:
                return Container();
            }
          }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using stream and state management. The `StreamBuilder` widget rebuilds is children when a new message appears in the stream.

Comment: how can i do this in my code?

Comment: @st4tic You need to do that in the children called in this code.